# SQL fill field with data from another record in same table

Tags: sql, field

```
contract  rec  #     state  dealer  coverage
--------  ---  ----  -----  ------  --------
55661     1    YUFL  FL     GP      GP15  
55661     2    YUFL  FL     GP    
55662     1    YUFL  FL     GP      GP16  
55662     2    YUFL  FL     GP
```

Coverage field is empty for REC '2'. How do I fill the coverage field with the same data from REC'1' with the same contract #? Table name: contract_ex

I.e.

```
55661 REC'2' coverage s/b GP15
55662 REC'2' coverage s/b GP16
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?. Do you want to update your table with that data?

Comment: I'm new at this. i don't know what RDBMS stands for. I cannot alter tables. I can only query.

Comment: Means "Realtional Database Management System". So, I was asking if you are using Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, etc (and the version too: "Oracle 11g, SQL Server 2008 R2....")

Comment: OK I'm using pdAdminIII

Comment: are you just trying to fill in missing data? essentially are you trying to turn:
`55661 1 YUFL    FL    GP    GP15    
55661 2 YUFL    FL    GP `

into:
`55661 1 YUFL    FL    GP    GP15    
55661 2 YUFL    FL     GP    GP15`

Comment: I reformatted your sample table to make it look clearer, but I'm not sure if I got everything right there (in particular, I'm not sure about the `#` column). Please take a look and feel free to edit as necessary.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to fill in the missing information which I had been doing manually when converting to excel. At this point, there are thousands of records and this is becoming time consuming. (# is the store#)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT  contract,
        rec,
        state,
        dealer,
        (SELECT coverage FROM YourTable
         WHERE contract = T.contract AND rec = 1) coverage
FROM YourTable T
```

Comment: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Comment: @Brandi So, do you have more than one row for one contract with `rec = 1`?, your question seemed to imply something different

Comment: yes. each contract has a record 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. The problem I have is with record 2.

Comment: @Brandi That's not what the error says, it says that you have more than one row with `rec = 1` for at least one contract.

Comment: To be clear, there is only 1 row for each contract with Record 1. Record 1 will only occur once per contract.

Comment: @Brandi The error says otherwise. What does this query returns: `SELECT contract FROM YourTable WHERE rec = 1 GROUP BY contract HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`?

Comment: just a heading "contract character(10)"

Comment: @Brandi *a heading*?, what does that mean?. Well, according to that query, then you **do** have at least one contract that has multiple rows with `rec = 1`

Comment: @Brandi Sorry, I don't get it, maybe it's because I don't know too much about Postgres; but are you saying that you have the name of the column stored as a row on your table?, did that query returned any rows??

Comment: No rows, and you are right. I found 3 contracts where the Record Type 1 has 2 rows.

Comment: @Brandi Yeah, the error was saying that. Then, wich value of coverage of those is the one you want?

Comment: @Brandi: Adding `LIMIT 1` to the subquery would fix the "more than one row returned by a subquery" issue. But that probably makes sense *only* if multiple `rec = 1` rows always have identical `coverage` values for the same `contract`.

Comment: SELECT  contract,
        rec,
        state,
        dealer,
        (SELECT coverage FROM YourTable
         WHERE contract = T.contract AND rec = 1) coverage
FROM YourTable T

Comment: where would i add LIMIT 1?